# Query / Code not returning required result

Tags: java, sql-server, database-connection, resultset

Following is my code, I am passing stateid and on basis of stateid I am retrieving data from table base_path.

The code works fine for the first iteration i.e. for stateid  = 1 it returns one result but for second iteration i.e. when state_id = 2 it is returning both the records i.e. where s_id = 1 and 2.

**How to resolve this and get only specific records where s_id = stateid ?**

**DB structure is :-**

```
s_id  base_formid           base_xpath
1          1        .//*[@id='collapse-text-dynamic-form-number-1']/div/fieldset/legend/span/a
2          2        .//*[@id='collapse-text-dynamic-form-number-1']/div/fieldset/legend/span/a



public static Map baseXpath(int stateid)
{
    Statement s2 = null;
    try {

        con=null;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl, userName, password);
        s2 = con.createStatement();

        String query = "SELECT  base_formid,base_xpath FROM base_path where base_path.s_id = " + stateid;

         ResultSet rs2 = null;
     rs2 = s2.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs2.next()) {
        int basepath_id = rs2.getInt(1);
        String base_xpath = rs2.getString(2);

        basex_path.put(basepath_id, base_xpath);


    }
        con.close();
        return basex_path;
```

Comment: Using SQL statements like that is a very bad idea. It's open to Injection. Consider parametrising your SQL or using Stored Procedures.

Comment: I am new to using sql, can you please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: I'm not familiar, at all, with Java, I'm afraid; so can't advise you on how to parametrise a statement in that. I'm sure someone will be able to though. My comment was more of a helpful warning of the implications of your current set up.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing parameters to your `select` query, I suggest you use PreparedStatement rather than a Statement. Below code may help you to achieve your desired results.

```
public static Map baseXpath(int stateid)
{
    PreparedStatement s2 = null;
    try {

        con=null;
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl, userName, password);

        String query = "SELECT  base_formid,base_xpath FROM base_path where    base_path.s_id = ?";
         s2 = con.prepareStatement(query);
         s2.setInt(1, stateid);
         ResultSet rs2 = null;
     rs2 = s2.executeQuery();
    while (rs2.next()) {
        int basepath_id = rs2.getInt(1);
        String base_xpath = rs2.getString(2);

        basex_path.put(basepath_id, base_xpath);


    }
        con.close();
        return basex_path;
    }
```

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: may be because your Map object `basex_path` is holding the previous result and so you are seeing all the records ie., 1 and 2

Comment: that was the issue Map was declared as static

Comment: That's great! If you feel my answer helped you, can you click the tick mark below the down-vote button(down array) so that others will know that you found the answer.